# How to Modify a host.json file to include Function Time out

Tags: azure, function

This is my current host.json, i need to add "functionTimeout": "00:10:00" to it. where do i put the time out code?
'''
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
}
}
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that's definitely your problem, then try this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
```

That might not be the cause of your problem though. In which case, consider providing more detail of what the symptoms are. A long running Azure Function is sometimes a hint you should reconsider the approach, e.g. breaking the job down into smaller parts.

Comment: I was just trying to extend the time out. of my function app. per other help form Stack overflow they say to add the functiontimeout to the host.json, i was unsure where to put it in the current host.json.

Comment: Ok. As above, then. Hope it helps!

Comment: Excellent! Pleased it works for you.